# Disable "more" button in share sheet in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiactionsheet, sharekit

I want to disable the "more" button in the share sheet.

Please check this image:

[image]

Is it passable?
Can any one help me?

My code below:

```
let objectsToShare:NSArray = [firstActivityItem]
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)


    vc.excludedActivityTypes=[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
        UIActivityTypePrint,
        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
        UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
        UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
        UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
        UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
        UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,"com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension","com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"]

myviewcontroller.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I just want to Mail,SMS,Facebook and Twitter. Is it passable to customize programatically.

Answer (score 1):

More will be automatically appear if you have sharing application list more then 4 items, if I understood correct.

So I would suggest lets click on the more and see what all the application list is coming for you then you should exclude all those you don't wan't here,

```
let objectsToShare:NSArray = [firstActivityItem]
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

vc.excludedActivityTypes =
       [UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
        UIActivityTypePrint,
        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
        UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
        UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
        UIActivityTypePrint,
        UIActivityTypeMessage,
        UIActivityTypeMail,
        UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
        UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
        UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
        UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
        UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
        UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
"com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension","com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"]

myviewcontroller.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Built_in_Activity_Types)

Comment: Is it customize? I don't want all. I just want to Mail,SMS,Facebook and Twitter. Is it passable to customize programatically.